# How to access WildFly Admin Console with RBAC provider (localhost)?

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

Changing from "simple" to "rbac":

```
<access-control provider="rbac">
  <role-mapping>
    <role name="SuperUser">
      <include>
        <user name="$local" />
      </include>
    </role>
  </role-mapping>
</access-control>
```

causes the following:

> {
>       "outcome" : "failed",
>       "failure-description" : "WFLYCTL0313: Unauthorized to execute operation 'read-resource' for resource '[]' -- \"WFLYCTL0332:
>   Permission denied\"",
>       "rolled-back" : true }

Which other configurations are required in standalone.xml for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue - defining only the $local user is insufficient, and you actually need to add additional users first, e.g.:

```
    <access-control provider="rbac">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local" />
                    <user name="myAdmin" />                     
                </include>
            </role>
            <role name="Monitor">
                <include>
                    <user name="myLogs" />
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
```